# What does multiplying a bit by 256 do

Tags: math, bit

I have seen people multiply bits by 256 before and im wondering why they do it and what it does?

```
local function getBits32(streamString)
  local W, X, Y, Z  = string.byte(streamString, streamPosition, streamPositon + 3);
  
  streamPosition = streamPosition + 4;
  
  return (Z * 16777216) + (Y * 65536) + (X * 256) + W;
end;
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, unless you mean bit-shifting by 8, which moves everything over by one byte

Comment: We'd need to see the code in question since there's many possible reasons for this.

Comment: Hint: 256 in binary is 100000000. Remember what happens to your decimal number when you multiply by 100000000? The number shifts left, and eight zeros are appended to the right. The same thing happens to your binary number when you multiply by 256, but in binary.

Comment: So I understand how it shifts the number over to the left by 8 bits but I dont understand what that does. Does it make the number 16 bits or something? Sorry if I sound dumb for asking this im just a bit confused lol this sounds like a pun now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that you posted combines four 8-bit numbers (bytes) into a 32-bit number. Each constant in the program, namely, 256, 65536, and 16777216, corresponds to a binary number with 8, 16, and 24 zeros after a single `1`. Multiplication performs a shift, in the same way that multiplying by 10, 100, 1000, etc. performs a shift in a decimal system.

To illustrate this last point, consider this function:

```
return (Z * 1000000) + (Y * 10000) + (X * 100) + W;
```

If we pass numbers between 0 and 99, inclusive, for `Z`, `Y`, `X`, and `W`, the function will combine them into a single decimal with our numbers "concatenated":

```
Z = 23
Y = 17
X = 42
W = 98
result: 23174298
//  Z = 23
//  Y =   17
//  X =     42
//  W =       98
```